# stack implementation (through nested classes)

Tags: class, c++-cli, stack, nested-class

im not sure if i understand correctly how this class works. its an example of stack.

```
ref class Stack
{
   private:

      ref struct Item // Defines items to store in the stack
      {
         Object^ Obj; // Handle for the object in this item
         Item^ Next; // Handle for next item in the stack or nullptr

         Item(Object^ obj, Item^ next): Obj(obj), Next(next){} // Constructor
      };

      Item^ Top; // Handle for item that is at the top

   public:

      void Push(Object^ obj) // Push an object onto the stack
      {
         Top = gcnew Item(obj, Top); // Create new item and make it the top
      }

      Object^ Pop() // Pop an object off the stack
      {
         if(Top == nullptr) // If the stack is empty
         return nullptr; // return nullptr
         Object^ obj = Top->Obj; // Get object from item
         Top = Top->Next; // Make next item the top
         return obj;
      }
};
```

i cant figure out how exactly Push function works. in the class definition its `Top=gcnew Item(obj, Top)`so basically it says that `Top` equals `Next`. So how does the `Stack` class determine the `Next` item if its always the one on the top of the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misinterpret the line:

```
     Top = gcnew Item(obj, Top);
```

It means:

- make the new item the top of the stack (which is ultimately what you want for a stack)
- set `Next` of the new Item to what was previously the Top

so by calling `Top->Next` you get to the previous item (the one "underneath" `Top`)